# Can I start httpd on a random port

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Is it possible to configure http to start on a random port ?
Instead of giving Listen 80, something like Listen * and then it listens on one random port ?

Comment: a random port so you have to find out? like a quiz?

Comment: exactly @ezra-s spring-boot does when you give port 0. It is usefull when you have multiple instances and want to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Apaches does not do anything like that, if you want to launch different instances set them up with the specific port yourself, or use named virtualhosts to have many different ones with the same ip:port combo to avoid such needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not possible, you need to specify the port.